# default stroke and fill in SVG

Tags: android, svg, fill, stroke

Im confused about stroke and fill defaults in SVG.

in the SVG spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperty) it says the initial value for the stroke property is none - which i am guessing is transparent? and the default stroke width is 1. and default stroke-opacity should be 1 too

Similarly for filll (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperty) the default should be black and opacity 1

Inkscape, and browsers seems to assume stroke = black and fill is transparent though - is that right? Does any one know what the defaults should be? and my rendered SVG seems to be at odd whith what browser and inkscape show...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stroke=none means no stroke at all, which is slightly different from just being transparent (stroke=<any color> combined with stroke-opacity=0 is what I would consider transparent).

The spec says what the defaults are for fill and stroke. I haven't seen any svg viewer that gets that wrong so far. Do you have an example svg?